# How to play customized alert sound on browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, audio, browser

I would like play a customized alert sound on the browser. It will play from a .wav file I created.

Currently, I am using AngularJS to create an alert by using `$window.alert(alert_msg)`. However, there is no sound with this function. How can I play a customized alert sound on browser when the alert box pops out?

The AngularJS way will be preferred. Otherwise, normal javascript or jquery will be fine too.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds cannot be played unless they are initated by some sort of user action - are you triggering the alert on a user action such as a click?

Comment: No. I am checking the backend database for some arrival of new data to trigger the alert. Is this going to be a problem? Is there no built-in function to simply play sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it and i do it in my app when certain actions happen:

```
var mp3 = $('<audio id="soundHandle" style="display:none;"></audio>').attr('src','sound/plop.wav');

$(mp3)[0].play();
```

so you're creating the object in jquery and then you simply target the object and hit play

Answer (score 1):

You might need to write a custom dialog instead.

See this for example

[Bootstrap 3 & AngularJS Dialog/Modals](http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/ALsdF)